# Execute the contents of a register

Tags: vimrc

Let's say I have the following text which I highlight:

```
s/ /","/g
```

And then I yank it into the `a` register:

```
"ay
```

How do I then run those commands? I thought doing `@a` would execute those commands, but it seems to just 'paste' in the text of the command. How would this be done?

Comment: Should we explain the difference between Normal mode and Command-line mode again?

Comment: @Matt -- I had forgotten to add the `:` at the start of the command, and then it worked when yanking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal mode command `@a` will execute the contents of register `"a` in normal mode, as if they were a mapping.

To instead execute the contents of `"a` as an ex command, use the ex command, `:@a`.

See `:help :@` for more details, and note that, in versions of Vim prior to 8.2.0997, [line continuations in the register will not work when executing code in this way](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/25008/343).

Comment: Note that after patch 8.2.0997, you can execute the contents of a register with line continuation. Refer to the below link for more information.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/2t1FG3ePcNg

Comment: @YegappanLakshmanan Thanks for the tipoff. (And for fixing the issue!)