# Execute vimscript without saving first?

Tags: vimscript

From my [two](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27287/running-function-using-sid-on-commandline-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1) [previous](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/any-way-to-execute-vimscript-beside-yanking-and-doing-on-the-commandline) questions, I learned about using `:source %`, `@"`, and other tricks to execute vimscript.

But as I noticed, `:source %` needs the file to be saved first, furthermore, `@"` and any other trick using registers don't always [work](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27284/30351).

Not needing to save first to execute something is very important for debugging/testing your code (as I'm sure many are already aware).

So is there truly no way to execute Vimscript (without as much restrictions as using registers has) without saving first?

Comment: There is, of course, the hack of remapping something to `:w | source %`. This answers your use case, but for the sake of knowledge (much more important :P), it does not answer question. I am searching for a way to use something like the `source` command on a buffer instead of a file, now. Cool question :)

Comment: Try this: https://0x0.st/iIUL.txt ; to use it, visually select the code you want to run, then execute `:@*`.

Comment: That actually work :O. Though the use of temp file is a little downside hmm (since this still save the content somewhere) @user938271 also, how does it work? don't think i see you using `source` on the temp file hmm

Comment: Thanks! had to search first if this question was asked before...seems it wasn't (afaik). @AriSweedler

Comment: Short of looping and doing `execute getline('.')` (or joining the lines and exec’ing), I’m not aware of anything. And those two usually have issues with line continuations/command separators.

Comment: It does execute `:source`; it's just written in the short form `so`.  In my experience, writing the code in a tempfile does not cause issues; they should be automatically removed as soon as you quit Vim.  There are [other similar techniques](https://github.com/lacygoill/vim-source).  If you use tmux, you can [run the code in another pane](https://github.com/lacygoill/vim-tmux/blob/5978a3b2febae50ee6c754f571397a8187345e64/autoload/tmux/run.vim#L390-L455), which is especially useful when you're trying to debug a crash (I'm doing it right now); you don't want your main Vim instance to crash.

Comment: That's too bad :/. Maybe a possible fix would be to make `execute getline('.')` continue until it find a newline, which might go around the mentioned problem with line continuations/command separators. @D.BenKnoble

Comment: I see! I don't mind if there temp files, but I'm mostly worried about disk i/o, since Vim already does a lots of operation on temp files (internally, like .swp file etc) and what other plugins does too. But i guess it is of minor worry since it is deleted after Vim close, though I'm also worried about when i don't close Vim for a long amount of time testing things, which will end up filling my disk with temp files! Didn't thought of using Tmux panes for this either :D @user938271

Comment: `Maybe a possible fix would be to make execute getline('.') continue until it find a newline, which might go around the mentioned problem with line continuations/command separators.` See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25020/22797)

Comment: Seems like your previously posted example work but only the first time. Described the issue [here](https://github.com/lacygoill/vim-source/issues/1) @user938271 :D

Answer (score 5):

vim9 has updated `:source` command and now you can:

1. `:%source` whole buffer without saving it, or just `:source`
2. `:'<,'>source` a visually selected lines
3. and basically range of lines, e.g. `:3,10source`

Comment: It also works with Neovim 0.8.2

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go, sorry it's late:

```
function! RunVimscript()
    new
    setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile
    let l:input = getbufline("#", 0, "$")
    call append(0, split(execute(l:input), "\n"))
endfunction
```